# No serializer defined for type: System.Drawing.Color

Tags: protobuf-net

In order to decrease the network traffic, I want to use protobuf-net to instead of the `BinaryFormatter`, But the following error happened:

```
No serializer defined for type: System.Drawing.Color
```

**WBMessage:**

```
[ProtoContract]
[Serializable]
public abstract class WBMessage
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Color setColor1;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public UInt16 userNo;

    public abstract WHITEBOARD_MESSAGE_TYPE MessageType
    {
        get;
    }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string age;

    public enum WHITEBOARD_MESSAGE_TYPE
    {
        enWBBegin,
        enWBLine,
        enWBRectangle,
        enWBRectangleF,
        enWBEllipse,
        enWBEllipseF,
        enWBClearScreen,
        enWBText,
        enWBEnd
    };
}
```

**WBMsgDrawBegin:**

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(WBMessage))]
public class WBMsgDrawBegin : WBMessage
{
    private const WHITEBOARD_MESSAGE_TYPE m_enMsgType =   WHITEBOARD_MESSAGE_TYPE.enWBBegin;
    public override WHITEBOARD_MESSAGE_TYPE MessageType
    {
        get
        {
            return m_enMsgType;
        }
    }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int x;

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public int y;

    [ProtoMember(6)]
    public bool m_bMouseDown;

    [ProtoMember(7)]
    public string name;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
WBMsgDrawBegin item1 = new WBMsgDrawBegin();
item1.setColor1 = Color.AliceBlue;
item1.name = "test";
item1.age = "31";

item1.x = 10998;
item1.y = 10089;

Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix<WBMsgDrawBegin>(ms, item1, PrefixStyle.Base128, 0);
```

Comment: could you please include the rest of the WBMessage class definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't guarantee to handle every known BCL type, especially from things like graphics libraries, that are not supported over all platforms. I would recommend:

```
public Color Foo {get;set;}

[ProtoMember(n, DataFormat=DataFormat.Fixed)]
private int FooSerialized {
    get { return Foo.ToArgb(); }
    set { Foo = Color.FromArgb(value); }
}
```

which will serialize it as a fixed 4-byte chunk. If you have lots of color properties, you could also use a "surrogate" to do something very similar (less code, but an extra 2 bytes per item).

Comment: Marc,thank you for your answer, my problem is resolved. More one question, could you tell me how to serialize the the data type of Point.

Comment: @Hudson which exact type of `Point`? there are a few, from different frameworks

Comment: Now I am development a project with visual c# and the framework's version is V3.5

Comment: This solution requires a separate property for every `Color` value to be serialized. "Surrogates" seem like a better solution, although I don't think this allows you to store the color as a primitive integer (i.e. a surrogate has higher overhead and is not binary compatible with the above solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405160/how-to-serialize-a-closed-immutable-type-with-protobuf-net

Answer (score 2):

So what's the question?

There is no serializer for the built-in color classes.

If you want to communicate color over the wire, you are going to have to do so in some other representation, such as sending a 32-bit integer for ARGB, which is pretty common practice for color.

There are many standard ways of communicating color.  I suggest you stick to a standard way of doing so rather than trying to define your own, though.  Just stick with a 32-bit integer or 4 bytes ARGB.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am fresh man of .Net development, so always use the default data type, for example color, i use the System.drawing.color class, point i use the System.drawing.Point class. Now according to your suggestion, the problem of color has resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was wrestling with something similar all morning, I'll add that another way to store Point, Size, Rectangle and Color etc is to use NET's built in converter.  The code is in VB, but you should get the drift well enough:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.ComponentModel

Private Function GetInvariantString(ByVal v As Object) As String
    Dim conv As TypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(v.GetType)
    Dim t As System.Type = v.GetType

    ' at least in VB '=' and 'Is' are not defined for Boolean 
    '  and System.Type so I cant find a way to word the Case 
    '  test so, it's inverted...only one Case can be true anyway
    Select Case True
        ...
        Case t Is GetType(Drawing.Point)
            Return conv.ConvertToInvariantString(v)

        Case t Is GetType(Drawing.Size)
            Return conv.ConvertToInvariantString(v)

        Case t Is GetType(Drawing.Color)
            Return conv.ConvertToInvariantString(v)

        Case Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("Unknown Type " & v.type.ToString)
    End Select

End Function
```

The simple approach of `myPoint.ToString` will return something like `{X=11 Y=156}` but there is not always a complementary `FromString` method for the Types being dealt with here.  `ConvertToInvariantString` returns `11, 156` and can be used to reconstitute the Point (and the rest):

```
Private Function TypeFromInvariantString(ByVal pbnString As String,  _
            ByVal ttype As Type) As Object

    ' same thing...
    Select Case True
        Case ttype Is GetType(Point)
            Return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Drawing.Point)).ConvertFromInvariantString(pbnString)

        Case ttype Is GetType(Size)
            Return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Drawing.Size)).ConvertFromInvariantString(pbnString)

        Case ttype Is GetType(Color)
            Return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Drawing.Color)).ConvertFromInvariantString(pbnString)

        Case Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("Unknown Type " & ttype.ToString)
    End Select


End Function
```

Rectangles, SizeF and the like (even Fonts) can all be handled the same way.  Personally, for `Color` I rather like storing/passing an Int representing the ARGB value, but the Invariant string method works well too, and if the color is a named color like "Red" then `Red` is all that is returned/serialized.  Usage:

```
' serializer version
<ProtoMember(6)> _
Private Property PBNImgPoint() As String
    Get
        Return GetInvariantString(_ImgPoint)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _ImgPoint = TypeFromInvariantString(value, GetType(Point))
    End Set
End Property

' method used in code/program....
Friend Property ImgPoint() As Point
    Set(ByVal value As Point)
        _ImgPoint = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return _ImgPoint
    End Get
End Property
```

Obviously, the conversion can happen in each Getter/Setter instead of a called procedure, but my pilot/test case has multiple Points, Rectangles and Sizes and I wanted to make sure they all got handled the same.

HTH