# "Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: Leap.Vector" error. using Protobuf-net serializer

Tags: c#, serialization, vector, deserialization, protobuf-net

I'm in the process of developing an application which uses the leap motion device and to be implemented using C#, my problem is that i want to store the list which contains the Vectors in my database. So i have thought about a solution of transforming the vector into an array of floats the problem is that each list contains a maximum and a minimum of 300 values (storing that into the database takes a load of time).

So i've search for other possible ways of storing and i ended up onto the topic of .net serialization. I had tried implementing the built-in .net serialization. Thought it worked, but still again it will took about a minute of serializing the list. So another solution proposed on the topic is to use the protobuf-net. so i'd tried and installed it using the nuget package installer. And ended up with this function (copied from the solution [Fastest way to serialize and deserialize .NET objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143421/fastest-way-to-serialize-and-deserialize-net-objects))

```
public static byte[] Serialize(List<Vector> tData)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, tData);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static List<Vector> Deserialize(byte[] tData)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(tData))
    {
        return ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<List<Vector>>(ms);
    }
}
```

But running the code will lead me to the error stated above(the title).

I think the error will happen at: `ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, tData);`

Comment: What does `Vector` here look like? Types in protobuf-net can be configured at runtime, but I need some clues as to what it looks like... is the library available on nuget, for example?

Comment: Is this your `Leap.Vector`?  https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/csharp/api/Leap.Vector.html  If so, an identical solution to the one from [No serializer defined for type: System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33495897/3744182) should work.

Comment: I *suspect* that all you need is: `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Vector), false).Add("X", "Y", "Z");` somewhere at the start of your app, and it will start working. It is happy to infer contracts for tuple-like types, but in this case I think there are some additional calculated properties that are making it confused (not knowing how to map the calculated properties to the constructor). Very hard to tell without access to `Vector`, though. The surrogate approach that @dbc linked to is another option.

Answer (score 0):

@dbc has already linked to similar code re `Point3D`, but I wonder if *any* serializer is needed here. This looks simple enough to just do raw (note I've assumed that `float` is the underlying data type here; if not, just change all `sizeof(float)` and `float*` to the correct type):

```
static unsafe byte[] Serialize(List<Vector> vectors)
{
    var arr = new byte[3 * sizeof(float) * vectors.Count];
    fixed(byte* ptr = arr)
    {
        var typed = (float*)ptr;
        foreach(var vec in vectors)
        {
            *typed++ = vec.X;
            *typed++ = vec.Y;
            *typed++ = vec.Z;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
static unsafe List<Vector> Deserialize(byte[] arr)
{
    int count = arr.Length / (3 * sizeof(float));
    var vectors = new List<Vector>(count);
    fixed (byte* ptr = arr)
    {
        var typed = (float*)ptr;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var x = *typed++;
            var y = *typed++;
            var z = *typed++;
            vectors.Add(new Vector(x, y, z));
        }            
    }
    return vectors;
}
```

If you're *really* brave, you could also try dumping the underlying data *directly* rather than copying the fields manually; that would be worth a try if `sizeof(Vector)` is exactly `3 * sizeof(float)` (or whatever the underlying type is).

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply sir and thank you for the immediate response. The above code works magnificently! Care to explain how those functions work. It's still my first time encountering unsafe codes. And why the process don't need any serialization at all?

Comment: @Neelneel the code shown *is* serialization; the point I was making is that you probably don't need an entire serialization library for this scenario. If we look at the `Serialize` method, what this does is: create a new array of the required size (3 values per vector); obtain a temporarily pinned pointer to the array's data (which will be a `byte*` pointer); coerce that into a `float*` pointer - essentially saying "that pointer: act like it is a pointer to `float` data"; then we iterate over the values, and for each we write the X, Y, Z values in that order; (part 1 of 2)

Comment: @Neelneel the `*typed++ = {some value};` is very subtle - `*typed = {some value}` by itself would be "assign {some value} to the memory pointed to by the pointer `typed`" - i.e. "write `X` to `typed`"; `typed++` by itself would be "increment the pointer by it's expected size" - i.e. "move typed forward by one `float`, so it is pointing at the next space". Put together, they do all of that in one operation, noting that `typed++` is **post**-increment, so we write `X` etc to the **old** location, not the **new** location. So: this writes the 3 values and we end up 12 bytes further; make sense?

Comment: @Neelneel the reason I'm using `unsafe` here is that it is very hard to get the **byte** values out of a `float` without doing allocations (for example, `BitConverter.GetBytes(float)` allocates an array each call) - so the efficient thing to do is to cheat - in this case by coercing a `byte*` pointer as a `float*` pointer - so we can write directly without ever trying to see the underlying bytes

Comment: That totally makes sense! Thank you again sir for helping me addressing my problem and clarifying it to me. Now I got to step further in developing my application. Hope I can trouble you again in case I will encounter some problems in the future.